# Handling access tokens expire time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, bearer-token

I am consuming some web API methods in my MVC projects. What I am doing is creating an API handling class. I am planning to get access token in the constructor of this class and then attaching it to my webapihandler object in the constructor again. Then I will consume several API calls which is fine. However, I think I have to control the expire time of the token before every call and if it is expired then I have to create one. I do not know how to check the expiry time of a token.

This is the first time I am dealing with tokens in such a way and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to save the access_token, refresh_token, token_expire_time and last_write in the database. the last_write is the time the access token was created and the token_expire_time should be how long until the access token expires in minutes or seconds for time accuracy.

from there you just compare the (last_write time + token_expire_time ) to the time now.

Remember to always use DateTime.UtcNow when comparing and saving the time in the database or else timezones with throw it off and it wont refresh properly.

Here is an example

Database Class

```
public class Token
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastWrite { get; set; }

    public int Expiration { get; set; }
}
```

Function to check refresh:

```
// call this to get the token before making API call
public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(Token token)
{
     string accessToken;
     if (token.LastWrite.AddSeconds(token.Expiration) <= DateTime.UtcNow)
     {
        // refresh and update the database with the new tokens/expiration
     }
     else
     {
          accessToken = token.AccessToken;
     }
     return accessToken;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time. is that possible to extract token_expire_time from token?

Comment: When you go through the authentication process you are given a token expire time with the refresh token, its just a matter of extracting it from the results and saving it in the database. If there is there is no refresh or expiration token, read the API docs because it most likely doesn't allow refreshing of the access token unless you authenticate again.

Comment: In response headers expires field says 1 Jan 1970  is this for token? 
cache-control: no-cache 
 connection: keep-alive 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 08:52:37 GMT 
 expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT 
 pragma: no-cache 
 server: nginx/1.15.8 
 transfer-encoding: chunked 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET 
 x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block;

Comment: i'm not sure what that is. Best to create a separate question with what specific API you are trying to use, how you setup authentication, and what you are trying to do. in this case i assume how to setup access token refresh with your specific API

Comment: Thank you so much Graham, I will definitely do it.